# Как работает цикл for в данной ситуации?

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на выходе получается count = 14? У меня выходит 12, где моя ошибка?

```
public class Mix4 {
    int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[20];
        for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            m4a[x] = new Mix4();    // в каждый элемент создаем объект с ссылкой m4a
            m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1; // 0 + 1 = 1; 1 + 1 = 2;
            count = count + 1; // 0+1=1; 2+1=3; 3+1=4; 4+1=5; 6+1=7; 8+1=9; 9+1=10; 10+1=11;11+1=12;
            count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x); // 1+1=2; 3+1=4; 4+1=5; 5+1=6; 7+1=8; 9+0=9; 10+0=10; 11+0=11; 
        }
        System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1].counter);
    }

    public int maybeNew(int index){
        if(index < 5){
            Mix4 m4 = new Mix4();
            m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;
            return  1;
        }
        return  0;
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем смысл функции `maybeNew` и особенно кода `Mix4 m4 = new Mix4(); m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;`? Она же просто возвращает `1` или `0` в зависимости от индекса, к чему создавать `Mix4`?

Comment: это задача из HeadFirst. Меня просто интересует как count в данном случае будет равен 14.

Comment: Нужно воспользоваться отладчиком и смотреть, что происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде цикл от `0` до `8` (включительно), а это 9 итераций.

На каждой итерации вы обязательно увеличиваете `count` на `1` и еще на `1` если значение индекса меньше `5` (условие в `maybeNew`):

Т.е. в первые 5 итераций (от `0` до `4`) у вас будет в `count = 10` (`5` * `2`), а в оставшиеся 4 итерации (от 5 до 8) добавится только по `1`, вот и набралось `14`:

Добавьте в коде вывод в консоль:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
    ...
    System.out.println(String.format("#%s. %s", x, count));
}
```

и получите подтверждение:

```
#0. 2
#1. 4
#2. 6
#3. 8
#4. 10
#5. 11
#6. 12
#7. 13
#8. 14
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Sayat, пожалуйста, а [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)